# How to accommodate specflow step definition to accept deferent number of parameters from specflow feature file with one method

Tags: c#, specflow

Hi I have below Specflow feature files

**First scenario**

```
 Scenario outline:
    Given Add two numbers <num1> <num2> <num3>
    Then divide by <num4>
    Examples:
    |TestCase|num1|num2|num3|num4|
    |Add     |1   |2   |3   |4   |
```

**Second Scenario:**

```
 Scenario outline:
    Given Add two numbers <num1> <num2>
    Then divide by <num4>
    Examples:
    |TestCase|num1|num2|num4|
    |Add     |1   |2   |4   |
```

below is the code which I want in Step definition method

```
[Given(@"Add two numbers (.*) (.*) (.*)")]

[Given(@"Add two numbers (.*) (.*)")] 

public void Testtheconditionwith(string a, string b, string c = null)

{

}
```

this is not working. I don't want to write different methods with different parameters.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please format you code using the format code icon in the question editor. It is too difficult to read.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and paste it into the question editor.

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow doesn't support optional parameters in the step definition methods.
You have to write two methods, but you can simply call one from the other.

```cs
[Given(@"Add two numbers (.*) (.*) (.*)")]
public void Testtheconditionwith(string a, string b, string c)
{

}

[Given(@"Add two numbers (.*) (.*)")] 
public void Testtheconditionwith(string a, string b)
{
    Testtheconditionwith(a,b,null)
}
```

Better would be to use the Driver pattern. More about it at: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Guides/DriverPattern.html